# Reading the excel file into pandas data frame without hidden rows or ignore the hidden rows in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have struck to read the excel file after ignoring the hidden rows into pandas Data frame. After lot of  search I got the answer as below. Hope this will help some ones.

```
file_path ='text.xlsx'

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
ws = wb['Table1']

hidden_rows = []
for rowLetter,rowDimension in ws.row_dimensions.items():
    if rowDimension.hidden == True:
        hidden_rows.append(rowLetter)
print(len(hidden_rows))
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
#df.index += 2 (may some time we need adjust the data frame index to match 
# index of excel.
print(list(set(df.index)-set(hidden_rows)))
unhidden = list( set(df.index) - set(hidden_rows) )
newdf = df.loc[unhidden]
newdf.shape
```

Comment: This involves loading the same data twice.

Comment: Is there any effective solution?